# Can't store OneToMany relationsship in my Database

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, entity

I have a problem with the relationsship @OneToMany in JPA. I want to save a relationsship between a Customer and a Message Object but i got a NullPointerException. I don't know why, because i thought that the follwoing code will work smoothly.

Here's what i trie to do:

```
            Customer  new = new Customer();
            new.setEmail(email);
            new.setUserId(userId);
            new.setLastname(lastname);
            new.setFirstname(firstname);
            new.setPhone(phone);

            quick.customerNew(new);

            Messages msg = new Messages ();
            msg.setMessage(message);

            quick.newMessage(msg);

            //Here i got the NullPointerException
            new.getCustomerMessages.add(msg);

            quick.customerUpdate(new);
```

The Customer Object and the Message Object are stored in the DB. But the relationsship dosen't exists and i got, as i said, the NullPointerException

```
 public class Customer implements Serializable {

   [...]

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "_id_info", referencedColumnName = "_id")
   private Set<Messages> customerMessages;

   [getter/setter]
 }
```

Comment: How is this JSF related (besides you **using** it)

Comment: This is odd to me. Does this compile with this new assigned to the customer?  It is a keyword.

Comment: does Message have the Customer as ManyToOne relationship?

Comment: whats that quick object btw.. please post your real code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Here i got the NullPointerException
new.getCustomerMessages.add(msg);
```

If this line throws the `NullPointerException`, it can mean two things: either "new" (geez, it hurts just to type it as a variable name) is `null`, or `getCustomerMessages()` returns `null`.

Since your code reaches this point, by accessing "new" multiple times before, I assume that "new" isn't the culprit here.

Since you never call `setCustomerMessages()` in your code, and there are no signs that any other calls would set your `customerMessages` attribute, I assume that this will be member you need to set.